# SQL C# Generating SQL statement with LIKE and wildcards; giving Incorrect syntax near 'bla'

Tags: c#, sql, syntax, quotes

So I have got an ArrayList called arr, which contains strings such as "decoration", "metal", "paper" etc.

What I want to do is loop though that ArrayList, adding each tag to a query string with which to get data from a database.
Currently I have something like this:

```
String strSel="select * from Table1 where Tags";

for(int x=0;x<arr.Count;x++){
  if (x == arr.Count - 1)
    {
      strSel += " like '%'"+arr[x]+"'%'";
    }
      else
    {
      strSel += " like '%'" + arr[x] + "'%' or Tags";
    }
}

cmdSel=new SqlCommand(strSel,connectionName);
sqlDataReaderName=cmdSel.ExecuteReader();
```

Anyway I get an error about "Incorrect syntax near bla"...its has probably got something to do with the single quotes or wildcards but I can't figure it out. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should remove extra single quote *before* and *after* the `percent symbol`

```
strSel += " like '%" + arr[x] + "%'";
```

the reason why error has been thrown is because your query is formed like this

```
select * from Table1 where Tags like '%'hello'%'
                                       ^     ^ extra single quote that
                                               should be removed
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes Kuya John is correct the extra ' is causing the issues

```
        String strSel = "select * from Table1 where Tags";
        string[] arr = new string[] { "This", "That", "Something" };
        for (int x = 0; x < arr.Count(); x++)
        {
            if (x == arr.Count() - 1)
            {
                strSel += string.Format(" like '%{0}%' ", arr[x]);
            }
            else
            {
                strSel += string.Format(" like '%{0}%' or Tags", arr[x]);
            }
        }
```

This performs fine withot the extra '